# Do I need to download migrate upgrade module if use drush command?

Tags: drush, upgrading

Migration Drupal 6 to Drupal 8.

My Drupal 8 site is located at /domains/example.com/public_html/drupal8site

**Step 1**: Install Drush

**Step 2**: Browse my drupal site `cd /domains/example.com/public_html/drupal8site`

**Step 3**: Use drush command `drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://user:pass@12.34.56.78/d6db --legacy-root=http://example.com`

If I using Drush migrate command above, do I still need to download the [Migrate Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) module? If yes, where should the module file located?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it clearer: The migration system is part of Drupal core.
The [Migration Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) module, whose 4.0.x branch is declared compatible with Drupal 9 and Drupal 10, only provides the front-end to the upgrade process from Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 to Drupal 8, Drupal 9, or Drupal 10. It also provides two Drush commands, described in the [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_upgrade/-/blob/4.0.x/README.txt) file.

- migrate-upgrade - performs a complete import of the source site's
  configuration and content into the target Drupal 8 site. Optionally, with the --configure-only flag, it may create migration configurations for such an import without actually running them, to permit customization of the import process.
- migrate-upgrade-rollback - removes content and certain configuration
  previously imported either by the migrate-upgrade command or by the core upgrade UI.

To answer to *Do I still need to download the Migrate Upgrade module?* I would check the [usage statistics page for the module](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/migrate_upgrade), which makes evident that the mostly used release is the 8.x-3.2, which runs in either Drupal 8 or Drupal 9, and it's installed in 5.000 sites. The 4.0.0 release (compatible with Drupal 9 and Drupal 10) is used from 716 sites. (Those data are updated to July 3, 2022.)
Those statistics make clear the module is still used; I take them as meaning that the module can still be used. Using it is up to you, but it seems there is still a need for it, at least in some cases.

The module is a normal Drupal module, you install it as any other module, and place its files as you would do with other modules.

As side note, for more Drush upgrade commands, there is the [Migrate tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools)  module, which implements the following commands.

- migrate:status - Lists migrations and their status
- migrate:import - Performs import operations
- migrate:rollback - Performs rollback operations
- migrate:stop - Cleanly stops a running operation
- migrate:reset-status - Sets a migration status to idle if it's gotten stuck
- migrate:messages - Lists any messages associated with a migration import
- migrate:fields-source - List the fields available for mapping in a source